# Create file name from variable values in python

Tags: python, dataframe, export-to-excel

I would like to create a .xlsx file using the name of an existing variable. I need to dynamically create the Excel name in df.to_excel for a given stock.  For example, create TSLA.xlsx for a data frame.

```
    ticker = 'TSLA'
    xlfile = ticker + ".xlsx"
    df=pd.read_csv(query_string)
    df.to_excel(xlfile, index=False)
```

I get Permission denied: 'TSLA.xlsx'

However the following works just fine:

```
    df=pd.read_csv(query_string) 
    print(df)
    df.to_excel("TSLA.xlsx", index=False)
```

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: `"TSlA.xlsx" != "TSLA.xlsx"`. Apparently, you don't have permission to write to `"TSLA.xlsx"`

Comment: That had no impact.  It works with TSlA and TSLA.

Answer (score 0):

As ForceBru said `"TSlA.xlsx" != "TSLA.xlsx"` and to overcome the permission denied, simply run as root user.
`sudo python3 yourFile.py`